# using DOMFormControlElement set value dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jxbrowser

I'm using JxBrowser with a Java program executing an index.html file as a GUI to enter and display values.

I'd like to update one HTML form dynamically from my java app, using code below:

```
browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
      if (event.isMainFrame()) {
        DOMDocument document = event.getBrowser().getDocument();
        DOMFormControlElement element = 
                    (DOMFormControlElement) document.findElement(By.id("textArea"));
        DOMFormControlElement textArea = (DOMFormControlElement) element;
        DOMEventType.OnChange;  
        if (!MessagefromCSM.equals("CSM request pending")) {
            textArea.setValue(MessagefromCSM);
        }
     }
   }
});
```

this works perfectly when launching, string value from MessagefromCSM is correclty displayed, but remains static.
is there anyway to update textArea at will?

thanks for any hint,

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello finally worked it out...

```
  final DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
  ((DOMFormControlElement) document.findElement(By.id("textArea"))).setValue(MessagefromCSM);
```

called where appropriated

I can close it now,
Olivier